# How to get rid of the port when `host.docker.internal` to interact with a service running locally on my machine

Tags: docker, networking, containers, devops

To make a service running in a container interact with another one running locally at let's say `localhost:3000`, we can use `host.docker.internal:3000` in the container code to make the required connection. But is there a way I can get rid of the port while using `host.docker.internal` so that it automatically routes to `localhost:3000`? That is, I just use `host.docker.internal` in my code instead of `host.docker.internal:3000`?

Clarification: I am not asing how to connect to localhost from inside the container. What I am asking is how to route `host.docker.internal` to the correct port without specifying it explicitly like: `host.docker.internal:3000`.

Comment: The default HTTP port is 80, and you'll need some sort of router or proxy if you need port 80 to forward to port 3000.  Using environment variables to configure external service locations is probably a good practice; it shouldn't make a difference whether or not there's a port number.

Comment: How can I route the port using environment variables?